# VBA paste selected range data to another file from a column to a column with the same name

Tags: excel, vba

I have one question. I would like the copied data range which is the result of find in the input box (Loc) in the code. For example, the column name 2020-02-01 was pasted into wbME.input_4 into the same column from which it was copied from another file. That is, if we chose the input Box 2020-02-01, it should be pasted into the column with the same name (date) in another file that I indicated.
From this , it is result

```
    Set loc = .Cells.Find(what:=Format(inputbx, "YYYY-MM-DD"))
        If Not loc Is Nothing Then
            lc = .Cells(loc.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            .Range(.Cells(109, loc.Column), .Cells(123, lc)).Cop
```

````
''' Put date input box  '''
    Do
        inputbx = InputBox("Date, FORMAT; YYYY-MM-DD")
        If inputbx = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
        On Error Resume Next
        vDate = CDate(inputbx)
        On Error GoTo 0
        DateIsValid = IsDate(vDate)
        If Not DateIsValid Then MsgBox "Please enter a valid date.", vbExclamation
    Loop Until DateIsValid
'COPY loop"
    Dim loc As Range, lc As Long
    With data_wb.Sheets("Final")
        Set loc = .Cells.Find(what:=Format(inputbx, "YYYY-MM-DD"))
        If Not loc Is Nothing Then
            lc = .Cells(loc.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            .Range(.Cells(109, loc.Column), .Cells(123, lc)).Copy
        wbMe.Sheets("input_4").Rows("1:1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues  <----- '''If result from loc match in columns in input_4 then paste'''
        ```
````

Comment: To the same rows on sheet input_4, that is 109:123 ?. You need to search the  input_4 sheet in the same way as you search the Final sheet `Set locPaste = wbMe.Sheets("input_4").Cells.Find(what:=Format(inputbx, "YYYY-MM-DD"))`

Comment: Its another 25:50. Does this affect it?

Comment: So you want `wbMe.Sheets("input_4").Cells(25, locPaste.Column).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues`. Since you have only copied 15 rows then this will fill rows 25:39